# magento 1.9 stock qty shipping message php code

Tags: product, magento-1.9, stock

EDITED---

Not sure what happend to the post.. Its missing most of my explaination.. Anyway..

I have existing code that shows a specific shipping time when certain variables of the product exist.. eg sku, cat id.. ect.

Here is the code that I am using for that

'

```
                            $sku_code = substr($_product->getSku(), 0, 1);  
                        ?>                          
                        <?php if (in_array(307, $_product->getCategoryIds())): ?> 
                            <?php echo $this->__('Shipped in 25 days') ?>
                        <?php elseif (in_array(317, $_product->getCategoryIds())): ?>
                            <?php echo $this->__('Shipped in 28 days') ?>
                        <?php elseif (in_array(300, $_product->getCategoryIds()) || in_array(302, $_product->getCategoryIds()) || in_array(304, $_product->getCategoryIds()) || in_array(308, $_product->getCategoryIds()) || in_array(310, $_product->getCategoryIds()) || in_array(357, $_product->getCategoryIds()) || in_array(359, $_product->getCategoryIds())): ?>
                            <?php echo $this->__('Shipped in 17 days') ?> 
                        <?php elseif (in_array(291, $_product->getCategoryIds())): ?>
                            <?php echo $this->__('Shipped in 2 to 5 days') ?> 
                        <?php elseif ($sku_code == 'F' || $sku_code == 'G' || $sku_code == 'P'): ?>
                            <?php echo $this->__('Shipped in 1 to 3 days') ?> 
                        <?php //elseif ($sku_code == 'A'): ?>
                            <?php //echo $this->__('Shipped in 28 days') ?> 

                       <?php else: ?> 
                            <?php echo $this->__('Shipped in 3 to 7 days') ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>'
```

What I am wanting to do however is add in a statment that checks if the product qty is at 0.. then display shipping days as a higher amount with message that it is on backorder.

I have tried the code `<?php elseif ($_product->getQty() <= 0 ): ?>
                                <?php echo $this->__('Item on backorder Ships in 7-21 days') ?>`

But it just displays the message regardless of the qty..(ie if its qty 2 it still shows') so I am wanting your advice on fixing my line.

Thanks

Comment: It will be easier to get help if you post more details, the most important one: what is your question? Right now we don't know if you want help to know _where_ to put the code, or if you want help because you have an _error_...anyway, be more specific and give us more details :)

Comment: Hi Bruno,, Not sure what happend to the post.. Its missing most of my explaination.. Anyway.. 

I have existing code that shows a specific shipping time when certain variables of the product exist.. eg sku, cat id.. ect.

Here is the code that I am using for that

Comment: No worries...glad you found an answer. Thanks for sharing that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this,
load in your file

`<?php $stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product);?>`

then

`<?php if ($stock->getQty()==0): ?>
                                <?php echo $this->__('ships in 21-28 days')?>`

in the code.  It now checks if the qty is 0 and not above or below. it works just as I needed for custom message.

Hope this helps someone else.

I also changed the instock to show as backorder on default.php so that when qty was 0 it showed as on backorder and not instock still as I have allow qty below 0 in backend.